# Can you create child cases from a repeat group in advanced modules in CommCare?

Tags: commcare

In CommCare, when using normal modules, you can create an unspecified number of child cases from a repeat group in a form.
Instructions here under "Opening Child Cases from a Repeat Group": 
https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Child+Cases

Is it possible to do the same thing in advanced modules?  This does not seem to be working for me, so I'm looking for confirmation that it's not supported.

Answer (score 1):

It is supported and works the same way as it does in normal modules in that you save questions form the repeat group to the case properties.